# create an openlayers map from mySql (non Spatial) which haves gazetter uri's

Tags: mysql, openlayers

I will need all the help of the experts!
I do have an mysql db which instead of spatial data has gazetteer uri's...

I was asked to build a dynamic map with openlayers (or any another js framework)  but I don't know how to proceed or how to start !!!

Shall i transform the db into spatial somehow?
--Although they may not allow me to mesh with their db.

Alternative can I somehow create a layer on the fly?
--layer features will come from mysql
--spatial info from the gazetteer

Can this be done at openlayers level ? Are you aware of such capability of geoserver/mapServer so as the later serve such a layer through WMS ??

Also other strategies/ideas are more than welcome !!

thx
g.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Just show points on a map?

Comment: Hi John, It will spatial data-> points/lines/polygons with their features eg. when you click/hover a popup will be raised containing more details ...

Comment: All the you ask for is possible with geoserver, openlayers, etc, but your question is very broad. You can connect geoserver and mysql, http://docs.geoserver.org/2.1.1/user/data/mysql.html, but I'm fairly sure you will want to use spatial columns.

Comment: I know that geoserver and/or mapserver will help me only if the db has already the spatial info. My problem is that db has a link to the spatial info. So either i have to perform some type of offline processing and make db spatial or do it on the fly .... for the 1rst I may think some options, but the second I have no clue ....